# Capacitor splash screen animation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4, capacitor

I have an Angular 2+ app wrapped with [Capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/).
I want to add a splash screen animation to it.

After researching this issue I understood that animating the splash screen is not possible, but we can wait until the app is launched and add the animation to it.

Can someone explain the process of loading animation into an app?
How do applications load an animation upon app startup?
Sharing Android/iOS code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating Splash Screens and Icons** 
Follow the steps in [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons)

1. First install

   ```
   npm install -g cordova-res
   ```
2. Create a resources folder in the project with icon.png ( must be at least 1024×1024px) and splash.png (must be at least 2732×2732px). The resources folder should be at the same level as src folder.
3. Run the following commands for iOS/Android:

   ```
    cordova-res ios --skip-config --copy
    cordova-res android --skip-config --copy
   ```

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to integrate animation (not splash screen) using capacitor?